# Sql Client AddWithValue null parameter without @ sign

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure from class library project.

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

`myVariable` is null and the table column allows null.

I call the stored procdure like this :

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", myVariable);
```

and I get this error :

> Procedure or function expects parameter 'myparam' which was not supplied.

I set the parameter value like this :

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myparam", myVariable);
```

and it works.

Why does putting `@` sign before parameter affect the command? I have a lot of parameters passed without `@` sign before parameter name and they work if value is not null.

Sp content :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[medilit_sp_trnx_reports_insert]
    (@paramID BIGINT,
     @myparam NVARCHAR(1000)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO trnx_reports(paramID, myparam)
    VALUES (@paramID, @myparam);

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END ;
```

Comment: where is tour query?

Comment: You mean stored procedure name or sp content?

Comment: At a minimum, the definition where you specify what parameters it takes etc.

Comment: In fact it is not necessary to solve this problem because as I said it is working with @ sign before parameter name. Bu I edited question.

Comment: When creating the `command` object, are you setting its `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` ?

Comment: `DBNull.Value` is the value to pass to represent a `NULL` in a database, the fact the variable is`null` is not the same. Pass `myVariable ?? DBNull.Value` as the param value.

Comment: @JayV yes. I edited question.

Comment: @AlexK. I tried  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", myVariable ?? DBNull.Value); before question. But it was giving same error.

Comment: Can you add the full code that call the stored procedure

Comment: I cannot because it is thre pages of code.

Comment: Without seeing the code that creates and uses `command` this is likely not answerable. Post a simplified version that also fails, its just passing 2 params so should only be a few lines.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: I do not know why but casting optinional dbnull.value to object solved problem :  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", myVariable  ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

Comment: You do not know why because you did not read the link Richardissimo posted. That explains exactly why you had this problem and why you should not use addwithvalue.

Comment: @Richardissimo can you post as an answer. I will acept it. Late but will be helpful others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't pass `null` as a parameter value. If you want to pass a null value, you have to use the special object `DBNull.Value`. You could supply the proper DBNull value using the null coalesce operator like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", myVariable ?? DBNull.Value);
```

NOTE that your question doesn't make it clear what the type of your `myVariable` variable is, so the compiler might not be happy with that null-coalesce: it might say:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '*something*' and 'DBNull'.

So you might also need to cast that special value so that `myVariable` and it share a common type. The most obvious solution would be to cast to `object`, since both types will derive from that, so you could use either of these:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", myVariable ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparam", (object)myVariable ?? DBNull.Value);
```

However, as indicated in [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), don't stop there. Move away from using `AddWithValue` to using something like...

```
command.Parameters.Add("@myparam", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myVariable ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

(the example above is for a DateTime, and would need to be adjusted for whatever the type of your parameter is)